# изменить порт phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, nginx, phpmyadmin

здравствуйте, во время авторизации в phpmyadmin всё проходит успешно, но из-за того что к адресу сайта добавляется порт :80 то каждый раз вылазит такая страница,можно ли как то сделать чтобы во время авторизации перекидывало на ту же страницу, только не писало вначале :80? сервер Centos 7 (nginx+apache)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

$cfg[‘PmaAbsoluteUri’] = ‘[https://ваш](https://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88) домен/myadmin’;

это в конфиг pma